# Script envia email

Tags: javascript

Criei um script em uma planilha google, com o seguinte código, que deveria enviar um email, quando o tipo de alerta for diario, sendo que o envio, que pega o email da coluna F, só deveria acontecer se a situação estiver pendente(Coluna D). Porém, executo o script e não recebo o email.
OBS. A finalidade do script é me alertar que tenho uma tarefa a fazer, todos os dias.

```
function AlertaSimples () { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('AlertaSimples');
  var startRow = 0;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 3, numRows-startRow,lastCol).getValues();  //Get all values except the header rows

 //  var data = new Date();

  for (var i=0;i<numRows-startRow;i++){
    var auditor = dataRange[i][0]; //indice comeca em 0
    var meidas = dataRange[i][1];
    var tipoAlerta = dataRange[i][2]
    var situacao = dataRange[i][3]
    var obs = dataRange[i][4]
    var emailAddress = dataRange[i][5];

    if (tipoAlerta == 'Diario' && situacao =='Em Andamento' ) {

      var subject = "Prezado(a) " + auditor + ", o seguinte prazo: " + dataRange[i][1] + " vence em dias";

      var message = "ola"
      MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: emailAddress.toString(),
      subject: subject,
      htmlBody: message

      });
    } else {
      //não mandar email
  }
}
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: está muito vago *" não recebo nenhum email."*, acontece algum erro? já debugou e verificou o valor das variáveis antes de enviar?

Comment: Editei a pergunta: A finalidade do script é me alertar que tenho uma tarefa a fazer, todos os dias.

Comment: @Rogér, eu entendi sua dúvida, só que você já parou pra ver se não é seu "email" na coluna **EMAIL PARA LEMBRETE** que não está correto ?
Eu a uns dias atrás fiz uma planilha que envia emails, se você quiser dar uma olhada, me avisa se você vai precisar de acesso, se não me engano está liberado pra todos: https://script.google.com/macros/d/MeHEJ8rpoWF--vXGBz4-WsZJDjoEhHOGb/edit?uiv=2&mid=ACjPJvGaAxvgRLbqBjw2ok4ymMsv_2tTIl6JgAcGbYMdxus3PQERf0Moezt39YteYy9yINVtJJYmZWMpM65aIyw3fJ3LFwpiyaz3u6U1BWn-4LNRm6vKFgEK-3LfKcSyNnp6irzyWq6id28

Comment: o email ta correto. Logicamente, para publicar essa pergunta, eu resolvi colocar um ficticio. você pode liberar a planilha?